# How can I set the SYSDATE 10 years ahead with a default date of December 31? ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For example, SYSDATE + 10 = 09/08/2030. However, my result needs to be 12/31/2030.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't really want to change the value of SYSDATE so that `select sysdate from dual` returns 2030-12-31 ?!?

Comment: You *can* do that, but I don't think that's what you meant... Also did you actually want a PL/SQL answer, as you tagged with that as well as SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y'), (10 + 1) * 12) - 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + interval '11' year - interval '1' day
```

i.e. in plain SQL:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + interval '11' year - interval '1' day
from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY
-------------------
2030-12-31 00:00:00
```

or as you tagged with PL/SQL too:

```
declare
  l_date date;
begin
  l_date := trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + interval '11' year - interval '1' day;
  -- do something with it...
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=310e7a0a73594ee65fc2fc5296bc1912)

Truncating with YYYY gives you the first day of *this* year, 2020-01-01. Adding 11 (not 10) years gives you 2031-01-01, which is one day after you want; so taking one day off gives you the result you want.

Here the interval arithmetic is safe because it's always applied to the first day of a year, since the current date is truncated first.

---

I'm assuming you want this as part of a query, not for `sysdate` to [return a fixed date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/FIXED_DATE.html) for all queries across your database.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's not clear what exactly do you want, I'm going to add the answer to another interpretaion of your question:

There are 2 common ways to make `sysdate` return other specific dates:

**1. [FIXED_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2AE0D45E-C4EB-4A12-87F0-69F7CFF1CB30.htm#REFRN10062) system parameter. You can execute `alter system set fixed_date=...;'`:**

```sql
SQL> alter system set fixed_date='2030-12-31 12:45:56';

System altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2030-12-31 12:45:56

SQL> alter system set fixed_date=none;

System altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2020-09-09 12:32:45
```

**2. SYSDATE/SYSTIMESTAMP get datetime from OS, so you can shutdown database, change OS system clock and start database.**

PS. There is also another way for Linux, it's more difficult and absolutely not supported, but more flexible: [libfaketime](https://habr.com/en/post/503804/)

Comment: ALTER SYSTEM statement is a privileged operation usually issued by the DBA or someone with SYSDBA privileges

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add_months()`:

```
select add_months(sysdate, 10 * 12)
```

Oracle also supports the syntax:

```
select sysdate + interval '10' year
```

However, this might not work on leap days -- it returns an error instead of Feb 28 or Mar 1.  The first version returns Feb 28 on leap days.